# execute php endless script without using shell command

Tags: php, shell

I'm experimenting php for the first time and I'm having some issue by executing a server.php script that has an endless loop. I'm trying to do it because I'm using a free provider like 000webhost and I don't have tools to simply run a php script like so:

```
php -q server.php
```

I'm trying to build a simple chat using websockets, for this I need my script to be always running, so that he can accept, process and handle connections.
I've also used exec and other function to bypass this, but with no luck, I wonder, can I execute this kind of script by calling a simple php page?

Comment: The server will time your request out and kill it.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this???

Comment: Your only workaround server side security mechanisms limiting your scripts execution time is to respawn it ona regular base. but note that this is _not_ what php is made for. At least not as a module inside a web server.

Comment: @arkascha respawning would close all active client sockets - so it's not the right solution for the problem.  I do appreciate though that there's no simple solution.

Comment: Your architectural approach is questionable if closing the sockets is a problem. Such approach will _never_ be robust. Instead the sockets should auto reconnect, or, even better, not require a consistent connection at all. Take a look at "ajax long polling requests" instead.

Comment: Use heroku or something for hosting. Then you you can experiment for free with a proper websocket server (or language :)).

Comment: Since I'm interested in websockets, I think I'll try something with heroku and node.js next, the idea was a chat client, I didn't want to use local memory, I just wanted the server to be the middleware. I was trying to do this with php because I wanted to use this old provider account of mine.

Comment: @Fluffeh yeah I know, I just wanted to know if there was some workaround that was similar to call it from the shell in local.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the timeout before the script will be canceled by the server:

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

But this will only work if you have the rights for it.

Have a lot at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: No provider will grant this. Just think about what that would mean for them!

Comment: probably :), but when the script has to run the whole time this step is essential.

Comment: oddly enough it worked, sorta. The script is running, but the website became inaccessible few minutes after, I guess they have a max php script count per user or something like that.